# MySQL mysqli_fetch_assoc field name & value. How?

Tags: php, mysqli, resultset

The following code returns the field names of a result set. I also want it to return the values. How can I do this?

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach( $row as $field => $name) {
        echo $field."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `$name` holds the value in the loop. If you're not using a foreach, use `$row['id']` where "id" is the name of the column. The manual is great to find out stuff like this!

Comment: Checking the manual is usually quicker that posting a question: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php. Make it a habit of starting with that or you risk getting down voted.

Comment: My apologies. This is however the simplest and cleanest example of this solution I have found online. Hopefully it helps future searches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we assume that your array looks like this:

```
$row["first_name"] = "John";
$row["last_name"] = "Doe";
$row["username"] = "john.doe";
```

Using this code:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach( $row as $field => $value) {
        echo "{$field} - {$value}<br>";
    }
}
```

You will get an output like this:

```
first_name - John
last_name - Doe
username - john.doe
```

When you iterate through an array, using `=>` operator, you are iterating in a "key-value" pair style. Every iteration holds the `key` and `value` as you can see.

Take a look at [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for more information.

Comment: @Vini Glad it suits your needs. Take a look at the updated answer and don't forget to vote as correct answer :).

Comment: Just for thoroughness, how does one output both values to separate variables? Thanks a million again.

Comment: Go and write `var_dump($row);` and you will see that it contains a list of keys (first_name, last_name, username) and every key has it's value. I'm not quite sure how it's done in the background but it's not that difficult because you could get the list of keys, and then say something like `give me value for key first_name`, `give me value for key last_name`, `give me value for key username` and every received value is (re)assigned to the variable called `$value`. I'm out of characters but that's basically it.

Comment: [More information in the comment by John](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#120710)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the value in `$name` variable

```
foreach( $row as $field => $name) {
              echo $field . " = " . $name . "<br>";
    }
```